# 20 white balls are laid out in rows of 5 each. 4 balls are chosen randomly and painted black. What is the probability balls are from different rows?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Suppose 20 white balls are laid out in 4 rows of 5 balls each. 4 of
>   these balls are chosen randomly and painted black. What is the
>   probability of all the black balls being in different rows?

So first I can choose from any row. So say I pick a ball from row 1. Then I can only pick from 3 rows. So I pick from row 2. And so on. From each row, I can pick any of 5 balls. So I got:

$$\frac{20\times 15\times 10\times 5}{\binom{20}{4}}=\frac{5^4\times 4!}{\binom{20}{4}}$$

But this gives me a result greater than one. My professor's solution was:

$$\frac{5^4}{\binom{20}{4}}$$

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $5^4\cdot 4!$ counts the different orders of selecting the same balls.  The $20 \choose 4$ does not.  That is where the $4!$ comes from that is the difference in your answers.  To choose one ball from each row, you have five choices per row, so there are $5^4$ combinations of balls.

Comment: Right, it's as if I did $\binom{5}{1}^4$. My mistake was that I mixed up permutations and combinations.